# Access my Gmail account without access to Apple devices that I was previously signed into

Tags: gmail, security, account-management, android, apple-id

I cannot log into my Gmail account on any of my new android devices.

Google is requiring confirmation on an iPhone or iPad that I was previously logged into, but I no longer have access to either of them.

All this despite the fact that I disabled the verify sign-in safety net in Gmail! How can I login to Gmail without access to the Apple devices?

Comment: AFAIK, Google account doesn't allow remote access unless you have set up [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://remotedesktop.google.com) before, or are you talking about [Google's Find My Device](https://www.google.com/android)?